# Closeable lazy-seq in Clojure

Tags: clojure

I'm trying to create a lazy-seq which is also closeable. What would be the cleanest way to do that in Clojure?
Intended usage (but it's just one example, I can think of more usages for a closeable lazy sequance):

```
(with-open [lines (file-lines-seq file)]
   (consume (map do-stuff-to-line lines)))
```

Which in this case would be equivalent to:

```
(with-open [reader io/reader file]
    (consume (map do-stuff-to-line (line-seq file))))
```

Comment: Laziness and close don't generally work together well. For example, your intended usage demonstrates a bug: because `map` is lazy, the seq would be closed before you used any of its elements. Better to just make sure to process things eagerly, inside the dynamic scope of the `with-open` body.

Comment: Thanks @amalloy, I edited my code snippet to add a method for consuming the sequence. It's more about learning about how to add behavior on a lazy-sequence than this particular example.

Comment: Transducers lend themselves well for this: https://blog.michielborkent.nl/transducing-text.html

Answer (score 1):

Managed to get the intended usage with this wonderful piece of code:

```
(defn file-lines-seq [file]
  (let [reader (clojure.java.io/reader file)
        lines-seq (line-seq reader)]
    (reify
      Closeable
      (close [this] (.close reader))
      
      ISeq
      (first [this] (.first lines-seq))
      (next [this] (.next lines-seq))
      (more [this] (.more lines-seq))
      (cons [this var1] (.cons lines-seq var1))
      (count [this] (.count lines-seq))
      (empty [this] (.empty lines-seq))
      (equiv [this var1] (.equiv lines-seq var1))
      (seq [this] (.seq lines-seq))
)))
```

If there's a less ugly way to do this, please let me know.

Comment: And what is your usecase now? Close at some point and wait for the exception to throw?

Comment: The usecase is the one in the question.I don't understand why some say laziness and closeable are things that shouldn't be composed. Clojure is data in data out, but that doesn't mean to get all the data in (memory) before getting it out. Mapping input to output line by line seems a good idea. Maybe I'm missing something.